# Can you purchase Civilization V via retail and add to your Steam account? (Semi Duplicate)

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I'm looking at purchasing Civilization V sometime either today or tomorrow but was wondering if it can be added to my Steam account if store bought. I have really slow internet so would rather use a CD to install a game rather than downloading, although I'd really like to have the game on my Steam account.

I was reading similar questions and have read that for only certain games you can add them to your actual account. I read that for Civilization IV you can't do this if you purchase it via retail store, but was wondering if anyone might know if it works for Civilization V?

Comment: Is there any reason you would purchase it retail instead of through steam, if steam is what you're going to be using anyways? EDIT: I missed the part where you have slow internet.

Comment: Like I said in my post, I have extremely slow Internet (40MB takes over half an hour to download)

Comment: Be aware that there's probably a fairly large patch steam will need to download before you can play the game, and I don't think this can be skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Civilization V is Steamworks so you will have a cd-key that you can attach to your Steam account and you can either download it, or install it form the provided DVD.
Whenever you see Steamworks on the back of the DVD case that game will work only with steam. It is also mentioned in a box under the requirements that you need a steam account to play it.

You can view a full list of retail games that can be synced with Steam [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know, I wasn't aware of the Steamworks since mostly into MMORPGs. Thanks Edeph!